# Problems in moving the cursor with Google Lanterna Terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I am working with googlecode lanterna libraries. One of it's methods is "moveCursor(int x, int y)". I have a terminal field, and I want to move a character in it. But I'm having two problems:

The cursor does not go in the proper way it should. When I press Left Arrow  after I have been pressing Right Arrow, it goes some steps down, than goes the right way. That happens for all arrows.
And the second question. Can anyone help me to move a character in the terminal field? Should I build any class or any method? Or I should modify this?
Thank you!

```
public void movePlayer()
 {
  int xLocation = s.getXLocation();
  int yLocation = s.getYLocation();
  while (true) 
   {
    Key key = t.readInput();
    if (key!=null)
     {
      if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowLeft)
       {
        t.moveCursor(xLocation-1, yLocation);
        xLocation--;
       }
      else if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowRight) 
       {
        t.moveCursor(xLocation+1, yLocation);
        xLocation++;
       }
      else if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowUp)
       {
        t.moveCursor(xLocation, yLocation+1);
        yLocation--;
       }
      else if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowDown) 
       {
        t.moveCursor(xLocation, yLocation-1);
        yLocation++;
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this the cursor moves properly and without any complications.

```
public static void movePlayer() {
    int xLocation = s.getXLocation();
    int yLocation = s.getYLocation();
    while (true) {
        Key key = t.readInput();
        if (key != null) {
            if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowLeft) {
                t.moveCursor(xLocation - 1, yLocation);
                xLocation--;
            } else if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowRight) {
                t.moveCursor(xLocation + 1, yLocation);
                xLocation++;
            } else if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowUp) {
                t.moveCursor(xLocation, yLocation - 1);
                yLocation--;
            } else if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.ArrowDown) {
                t.moveCursor(xLocation, yLocation + 1);
                yLocation++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I could help you with your Problem.

To your second question I can't give an answer so far.